# How to make the anchor tag clickable without any redirect?or without any refresh?

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried

```html
<a
    href="_blank"
    target="_self"
    onclick={clickHandle}
    class="slds-hide_medium"
    title={label.Title}
    aria-label={label.Title}
> {label.Us}</a>
```

I also tried `href="_self"` , but these didn't work. I then removed `href` but now It is not showing that hand icon on hovering on the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `clickHandle` method you can call [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to prevent the page refresh / redirect.

```js
clickHandle(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // ... additional code
}
```

Please note that [a11y](https://a11y-101.com/design/button-vs-link) recommends using the following rule with anchor tags:

> A link is focusable and can be triggered by the enter key. A link will redirect you to a new page or a section within the same page. In VoiceOver's rotator, it will also be collected within the "Links" window.

Since you are using a custom `onClick` event handler I would recommend using a button instead of a link.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you developing in the **LWC**.
So for your case it will be **simple tag without any additional attributes** :

```
<a onclick={clickHandle} 
     class="slds-hide_medium" 
     title={label.Title}  
     aria-label={label.Title}>
     {label.Us}
</a>
```

Comment: You need an `href` if you want the link to look like a link.

Comment: href will redirect in another tab which I dont want.  Thanks. I want the pointer icon when  we hover on the link.

Answer (score 0):

Add some CSS:

```
<style>
a:hover { cursor: pointer; }
</style>
```